# Why i get error class undefined when declare friend funcion with class in multi file?

Tags: c++, class, header, friend-function

I created a friend funcion "display"(member of List class) in Nhanvien class.List was declared but it still keep this error:

```
C2027 use of undefined type 'List'.
```

I'm using Visual studio. How can i fix it?? Please help me. Sorry for my bad English :<

here is my source:

```
*//List.h*
#pragma once

#include"Nhanvien.h"

class Nhanvien;

class List
{

        Nhanvien* p;

   public:

       List();
       List(int);
       ~List();
       void display(int);
};


*//Nhanvien.h*
  
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include "Date.h"
#include"List.h"

class List;
class Nhanvien
{

private:
    
    char maNV[100];
    std::string tenNV;
    Date ngay;
    bool gioitinh;
    double luong;
    
public:
    
    Nhanvien();
    Nhanvien(const Nhanvien&);
    ~Nhanvien();
    void set();
    void show();
    static int count;
    friend void List::display(int);
};
```

[show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVsej.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a recursive dependency of headers.

*//List.h*

```
#pragma once

#include"Nhanvien.h"

//...
```

*//Nhanvien.h*

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include "Date.h"
#include"List.h"
//...
```

So the header `List.h` includes at first the header `Nhanvien.h` and this header does not see yet the declaration of the class `List`.

Comment: The solution here is to drop the include in List.h, the forward declaration of `Nhanvien` is sufficient. Also the forward declaration List in Nhanvien.h is unnecessary.

Comment: it works!! thanks so much for your help. it took me so much time to solve but you did it